# Creating Custom tab in Excel by JavaScript (json format)

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

```
Office.onReady(async() => {
  // If needed, Office.js is ready to be called
  const contextualTabJSON = `{
    "actions": [
      {
        "id": "executeWriteData",
        "type": "ExecuteFunction",
        "functionName": "writeData"
      }
    ],
    "tabs": [
      {
        "id": "CtxTab1",
        "label": "Contoso Data",
        "groups": [
          {
            "id": "CustomGroup111",
            "label": "Insertion",
            "icon": [
              {
                  "size": 32,
                  "sourceLocation": "https://cdn.contoso.com/addins/datainsertion/Images/Group32x32.png"
              },
              {
                  "size": 80,
                  "sourceLocation": "https://cdn.contoso.com/addins/datainsertion/Images/Group80x80.png"
              }
            ],
            "controls": [
              {
                  "type": "Button",
                  "id": "CtxBt112",
                  "actionId": "executeWriteData",
                  "enabled": false,
                  "label": "Write Data",
                  "superTip": {
                      "title": "Data Insertion",
                      "description": "Use this button to insert data into the document."
                  },
                  "icon": [
                      {
                          "size": 32,
                          "sourceLocation": "https://cdn.contoso.com/addins/datainsertion/Images/WriteDataButton32x32.png"
                      },
                      {
                          "size": 80,
                          "sourceLocation": "https://cdn.contoso.com/addins/datainsertion/Images/WriteDataButton80x80.png"
                      }
                  ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }`; // Assign the JSON string.

  const contextualTab = JSON.parse(contextualTabJSON);
  await Office.ribbon.requestCreateControls(contextualTab);

});
```

Comment: Is it Possible to add custom tab in excel by js or react js ???

Comment: Yes, it is. But you need to make sure that your host supports them by checking requirements sets specified in my post. Try running the sample project I mentioned. Does it work for you?

Comment: What exactly is the question? What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `onReady` callback is the right place for such things. Try running the following sample web add-in which creates a custom ribbon when selection is changed in Excel, see [Create custom contextual tabs on the ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/pnp-officeaddins/office-add-in-contextual-tabs/).

Custom contextual tabs are currently only supported on Excel and only on these platforms and builds.

- Excel on Windows (Microsoft 365 subscription only): Version 2102 (Build 13801.20294) or later.
- Excel on Mac: Version 16.53.806.0 or later.
- Excel on the web

Custom contextual tabs work only on platforms that support the following requirement sets:

- RibbonApi 1.2
- SharedRuntime 1.1

Read more about contextual ribbon tabs in the [Create custom contextual tabs in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/contextual-tabs) article.

Comment: thanks @Eugene Astafiev for your answer

Comment: @VikashChoudhary don't forget to vote/accept if your issue is resolved